# creating simple reusable component in Apache Tapestry5

Tags: components, custom-component, tapestry

I am starting an adventure with Apache Tapestry5. I am trying to make simple component (for tests), consisting of pair of Textfields. Component is named "TestComp". I have following elements:

testComp.tml

```
<t:container 
    xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">
    <p>
        <input t:type="TextField" t:id="testOne" t:value="testOne.input"/><br/>
        <input t:type="TextField" t:id="testTwo" t:value="testTwo.input"/><br/>
    </p>
</t:container>
```

TestComp.java

```
public class TestComp {

    private DataContainer testOne;

    private DataContainer testTwo;

    @SetupRender
    public void setup(){
        testOne = new DataContainer();
        testTwo = new DataContainer();
    }

    public String getContentOfTestOne() {
        return testOne.getInput();
    }

    public String getContentOfTestTwo() {
        return testTwo.getInput();
    }

    public DataContainer getTestOne() {
        return testOne;
    }

    public void setTestOne(DataContainer testOne) {
        this.testOne = testOne;
    }

    public DataContainer getTestTwo() {
        return testTwo;
    }

    public void setTestTwo(DataContainer testTwo) {
        this.testTwo = testTwo;
    }
}
```

And then I am trying to use it in other place, for example in index.tml:

```
<form t:type="form" t:id="out">
        <t:testComp />
        <br/><input type="submit" value="Component"/>
</form>
```

According to dozens of materials and examples I've found (to be honest non of it refereed to case similar to mine) such implementation should result of showing testComp element in the form, but unfotrunately there is nothing rendered above the button (though tapestry is not crashing). What am I missing? And will I be able to put in Index.java property of TestComp type and bind it with my

```
<t:testComp />
```

in Index.tml by id (or it requires something more to implement in my custom component?)

Comment: Is your template file starts with capital letter(`TestComp.tml`) or not(`testComp.tml`)?

Comment: Indeed, I'll check shortly if that was a problem.

Comment: OK, you were right, sody, changing case in testComp filename was the key. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You should mark the answer; yes, Tapestry is case sensitive in this one area: dealing with the filesystem.

Comment: To be clear, the name of the template file must exactly match the name of the Java class (but have the `.tml` extension).

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide the full index.tml file? If so, you are missing the tapestry namespace as well as a correctly setup html document. Try the following:

Index.tml

```
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>My page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form t:type="form" t:id="out">
            <div t:id="testComp" />
            <br/><input type="submit" value="Component"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your Index.java you can use this to access your component.

```
@component(id="testComp")
private TestComp testComp;
```

If this does not work there is probably something wrong in your configuration or setup and you might just be looking at a static tml file not handled by tapestry at all. In this case follow the step-by-step guide on the [Getting Started](http://tapestry.apache.org/getting-started.html) page.

Comment: Thanks for response. 

Firstly - I didn't attach full index.tml file, but it should be correct because I am performing my tests by modyfing official template application from maven repository, and generally it was working, by only my modification didn't want to (don't shows my component, rest of page loads normally). Secondly - I'll try to initialize my component as in example as you supplied - with DIV element.